# Making a counter with angular and timout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, timeout, counter

hey i'm trying to build a simple counter that shows in my html. it kind of works but it doesn't listen to the timeout and gives a bunch of errors.

This is the error i'm getting

```
TypeError: fn is not a function
```

This is the javascript function and object:

```
$scope.funFacts = {
    '1': {
        'text': 'Projecten',
        'amount': 3,
        'counter' : 0
    },
    '2': {
        'text': 'Blije klanten',
        'amount': 3,
        'counter' : 0
    },
    '3': {
        'text': 'Koffies per week',
        'amount': 15,
        'counter' : 0
    },
    '4': {
        'text': 'Pizza\'s gegeten',
        'amount': 45,
        'counter' : 0
    },
};

$scope.startAnimation = function(funFact) {
    var i = 1;
    $scope.ticker = function(funFact) {
        funFact.counter = i;
        i++;
        if (i <= funFact.amount) {
            $timeout($scope.ticker(funFact), 1000);
        }
    }
    $timeout($scope.ticker(funFact), 1000);
}
```

And this is the html i use to show and start the counter:

```
<section class="m-30">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="facts">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 fact text-center p-20" ng-repeat="funFact in funFacts" ng-init="startAnimation(funFact)">
                <h1>{{funFact.counter}}</h1>
                <hr>
                <h5>{{funFact.text}}</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the *function* and not the *function call* to `$timeout`. The first parameter should be a `function`, what you are passing is a `function call`. What you can do is this:

```
$timeout(function(){$scope.ticker(funFact)}, 1000);
```

Comment: Yep! that's it, thanks. do you know why we can't just pass the function call?

Comment: @SjoerdDeWit. as I explained, `$timeout` expects the first parameter to be a `function`. `$scope.ticker(funFact)` will return a value, so what you are doing here is passing a value as the first parameter.